# MySql null constraint violation within transaction

Tags: mysql, database, perl, transactions

Is there in MySQL possible to violate null constraints within a transaction in some way? I have some code in production which seems to do this be I cannot get it to work on my development machine.

The code is written in perl. This is what happens schematically:

1. Make an INSERT to get hold of an id, but not all non null values are set.
2. Make an UPDATE statement which sets all values.
3. Create data in other tables (and therefore it needs the id it gets in 1).
4. Commit the transaction (but I have not found an explicit begin transaction).

On my dev machine this fails in step 1 because it complains about fields not having default values. I have the same MySQL version (5.1.66) on both machines but production is running on linux and locally windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction guaranties [`atomicity`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) of several actions performed on database, not that you can violate constraints while using it.

Solution can be `insert` in which you don't violate constraints, either by using final values, or some temporary values which you override later using `update` during execution of your transaction.

Comment: Ok tnx. It is now solved. Something had gone wrong at the db export because it had missed a default value...